# JavaScript fill textbox with html content on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I currently have a div that contains a value of 'John Doe' and I would like to fill a text field with that value on another page of my site however I am unsure how this can be done?

I can do this easily on the same page by adding this JavaScript to a button:

```
document.getElementById('johndoediv').innerHTML
```

However I am now unsure how I can load the other page onclick and fill a text field with the value that the div contains.

Has anybody got any examples of something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the value static? If so, you can just do AJAX. Otherwise, you'll need to use cookies or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Your may use localstorage API

```
//Set a value
localStorage.setItem("data",myvalue);

//Get the value
localStorage.getItem("data");

//Remove data
localStorage.removeItem("data");

//Remove all data 
localStorage.clear();
```

You can also use `sessionStorage` with same methods than `localStorage`, but your data are only persisted while the browser is opened and then they are automatically cleared

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this in the smallest amount of code (without writing a full AJAX request yourself), I would recommend using jQuery's `.load()` function. This function can only load content into a div, but you could fairly-easily create a div with `display: none;` at the bottom of the page, load the content into that, and then put that value into your `input` element with a callback on the load function.

```
$("#throwawaydiv").load("otherpageurl #divonotherpage", function(){$("#inputbox").val($("#throwawaydiv").text());});
```

EDIT: This is assuming that the text in the div on the other page is static. If not, then all bets are off.